# Issue with [homescreen] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [homescreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homescreen) tag is currently Android-specific, although iOS devices also have a home screen. What should be done with this tag?

1. Leave it as is, and create a new tag such as **ios-homescreen**
2. Rename the current tag to **android-homescreen** and create **ios-homescreen**
3. Edit the tag so it applies to both iOS and Android

I believe 3 makes the most sense, as questions can separately have an **ios** or **android** tag. As evidence that "homescreen" should be a generic tag applicable to both mobile platforms, Apple uses the term "home screen" in this [iPhone basics support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TI169).

Any comments?

Comment: I think the usual term for iOS is [tag:springboard], but certainly [tag:homescreen] should not be Android-only.

Comment: @icktoofay Thanks for the comment. I believe Springboard is the name of the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it would make more sense to edit the wiki for [homescreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homescreen) tag to include both `iOS` and `android`. If we go on to create a separate tag for a generic concept for different languages, we'll end-up with cluttering the tagging namespace. For example, there is only a single tag for [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inheritance), or [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics) which is available in many different languages. So you can go for editing the tag wiki.

Comment: It looks like this answer is getting all of the support, and I found a support article (now linked in the original question) where Apple refers to the "home screen", so I will go with this. Thanks!